# Applying DBSCAN to a huge GIS dataset with a Haversine distance metric.

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-mining, gis

I have a training set (2GB) that contains GIS trajectory data for multiple taxi rides. I want to cluster the final destinations based on their spatial density and have therefore been trying to use the DBSCAN algorithm with the distance metric as the Haversine formula. As a baseline I was able to use K-means with minibatches/online by reading chunks from my pandas dataframe but I've had no success with DBSCAN (lots of comparisons).

I'm using scikit/python and have tried reading the csv into a Pandas dataframe and with GraphLab's SFrame. Any suggestions on how to do this with these tools? If not, what is the best way to apply clustering on such large datasets? I haven't tried directly working on a database.

Comment: Try ELKI. It has IMHO the best DBSCAN with data indexing. There was a blog somewhere on using it on Twitter coordinates (with Haversine, and also very big). Maybe doublebyte blog or something like that? Try cover tree indexing.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I am inexperienced with Java. Is there an implementation in Python?

Comment: You don't need Java experience to use ELKI. Only once you want to extend it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can certainly do this with scikit-learn/python and pandas. This tutorial demonstrates how to [cluster spatial data](http://geoffboeing.com/2014/08/clustering-to-reduce-spatial-data-set-size/) with scikit-learn's DBSCAN using the haversine metric, and discusses the benefits over k-means that you touched on in your question.

Also, this example demonstrates applying the technique from that tutorial to [cluster a dataset of millions of GPS points](http://geoffboeing.com/2016/06/mapping-everywhere-ever-been/) which provides a clear proof of concept for what you're attempting to do.

A couple tips from those tutorials: use the haversine metric with the ball-tree algorithm. And pass radian units into the DBSCAN fit method.